# How to install Kde plazma alongside unity in ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I'm just not sure how! Please help me to install the kde plazma alongside ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First :

```
apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop
```

When downloading and installation , it will ask you to configure **kde** :

Choose **kdm** after downloading , just logout and login as **kde** , it should work .

Comment: it works for me , mate .

Comment: you can not say probably , did you try it!